# Print Decision Tree Rules

Tags: java, tree, decision-tree

Suppose I have a simple tree with form like this :

```
3 --- 6 --- REJECT
        --- ACCEPT
  --- 2 --- ACCEPT
        --- REJECT
```

Now I know it doesn't seem like a tree, but that's not a problem. So, suppose we have a node (3) which has two branches that leads to leafs of Reject or Accept. So, in Java language, how can I print this tree in form like this :

3 6 REJECT
3 6 ACCEPT
3 2 ACCEPT
3 2 REJECT

Here's my code for print it preorderly :

```
public void preOrder(Node root) {
    if (root != null) {
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        preOrder(root.left);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        preOrder(root.right);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: And what the question is?

Comment: how do I print the tree, if the tree has four leaves, then it will print from node to leaf four times according to said leaves...